# Strange Swing error: setting GridLayout parameters makes my JPanel disappear

Tags: java, swing, layout

Don't know if I'm making a rookie mistake, but changing the row parameter when creating a GridLayout for a JPanel in my JFrame, seems to be causing another JPanel to vanish altogether:

Here's the stripped down version of the code:

- In the GridBug constructor I set up my layout and put a sub class of JPanel in BorderLayout.CENTER. This does other stuff in my original code, but here just draws a box to show it's being displayed.
- Somehow the state of the bottom panel which is added to BorderLayout.PAGE_END causes the center panel to vanish
- In particular, changing the GridLayout row parameters to a higher value causes the center panel to vanish, lower values work fine
- The code as it is now, does not work on my computer, if I uncomment some of the code to reduce row parameters, or if I don't add the JLabel or subPanels then it works...

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class GridBug extends JFrame{

    static class ImagePanel extends JPanel{

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize(){
            return new Dimension(200,200);
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
            super.paintComponent(g);
            System.out.println("Painting image panel...");
            g.setColor(Color.CYAN);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        }
    }

    public GridBug() {

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        /*PROBLEM CODE HERE*/

        //add center image panel - does not appear depending on GridLayout settings in other panels
        ImagePanel centerPanel = new ImagePanel();
        add(centerPanel , BorderLayout.CENTER);

        //add bottom panel
        JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel();
        add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        bottomPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(6,0)); //doesn't work
//              bottomPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(5,0)); //works

        JPanel subPanel = new JPanel();

        //if I pass more than 4 or so rows as param to gridlayout, 
        //then imagePanel is not displayed
        subPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,0));    //doesn't work
//              subPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 0)); //works


        //if I don't add this label - works
        JLabel label = new JLabel("A Label:");
        subPanel.add(label);

        bottomPanel.add(subPanel); //if I don't add the subPanel it works fine

        /*END OF PROBLEM CODE?*/

        //set window params
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(400,400);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }   

    public static final void main(String[] args){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new GridBug();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure the exact result you want, so I didn't even try. But the problem you're facing, is one of the reasons, you want to `pack()` your frame, and not `setSize()`. You're constricting the preferred sizes of the component. `pack()` respects the preferred size of all your components, and should be used, rather than `setSize()`

```
bottomPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(6,0)); //doesn't work..
                                            // with pack(), now it does.
pack();
//setSize(400,400);  // if you increase the size it'll work also, but just pack()
```

You just need to work on the laying out of your components now to get your desired look :)

---

A more detailed explanation of your problem.

[image]

This is how you code currently looks when I set the background. Note: you can already see the `setSize()` is taking a toll on your top panel's preferred size (200, 200).

- The top CYAN is your image panel.
- The BLUE is the `subPanel` with 4 row. With GridLayout, all the rows will be at least the size of it largest component. In this case it's the label. You can see the blue area is 4 times the height of the label (as it should be)
- Not the RED, which is the `bottomPanel`. This has 5 rows. The largest component is the `subPanel`, so the total size of the `bottomPanel` is the size of the `subPanel` x 5, as you can also see. Once you add another row, the top panel gets pushed out.

Comment: Thank you! I never normally use setSize() and forgot I had set it this time. I can't believe I spent ages testing masses of other code, thinking it was a completely different problem, and just left that one line alone.